# powershell windows missing updates

Tags: windows, powershell, updates

Trying to create powershell script to list missing or pending windows update. The purpose would be to run the script against a list of computers/servers to see if there are any missing updates or hot-fixes and generate a list of what servers you need to look at.

Does anyone have a solutions for this, have been looking around without any success finding scripts to do this.

Comment: Do you have a base list of updates that you want applied? Are these machines managed by SCCM, or some other patch management system?

Comment: Not really, the list I am looking for would be the windows update list and I would like to see f.e. for server1 a list of updates that has been issued but not yet installed on the server. Would be nice to group by importance so f.e. you might get - there are 6 updated pending 4 critical 2 optional etc.

I would like to add this to my script that runs every night and reports the up-time, reboot time and selected events from event log from selected servers I manage.

Answer (score 3):

Powershell script to list missing updates

**Script:**

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

#List all missing updates
Write-Output "Creating Microsoft.Update.Session COM object" 
$session1 = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session -ErrorAction silentlycontinue

Write-Output "Creating Update searcher" 
$searcher = $session1.CreateUpdateSearcher()

Write-Output "Searching for missing updates..." 
$result = $searcher.Search("IsInstalled=0")

#Updates are waiting to be installed 
$updates = $result.Updates;

Write-Output "Found $($updates.Count) updates!" 

$updates | Format-Table Title, AutoSelectOnWebSites, IsDownloaded, IsHiden, IsInstalled, IsMandatory, IsPresent, AutoSelection, AutoDownload -AutoSize

pause
```

**Sample output:**

```
Creating Microsoft.Update.Session COM object
Creating Update searcher
Searching for missing updates...
Found 4 updates!

Title                                                                                                               AutoSelectOnWebSites IsDownloaded IsHiden IsInstalled IsMandatory IsPrese
                                                                                                                                                                                           nt
-----                                                                                                               -------------------- ------------ ------- ----------- ----------- -------
Intel - Other hardware - Intel(R) Xeon(R) E3 - 1200/1500 v5/6th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) PCIe Controller (x16) - 1901                 False        False               False       False   False
Intel - Other hardware - Intel(R) Xeon(R) E3 - 1200/1500 v5/6th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) Gaussian Mixture Model - 1911                False        False               False       False   False
Microsoft Silverlight (KB4481252)                                                                                                  False        False               False       False   False
SQL Server 2019 RTM Cumulative Update (CU) 4 KB4548597                                                                             False        False               False       False   False


Press Enter to continue...:
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a sample script from TechNet that does the core logic you're looking for:

[Get-WindowsUpdates.ps1](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Get-WindowsUpdatesps1-7c82c1f4)

There's also the older [VBScript-based WUA_SearchDownloadInstall.vbs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: There's actually an entire [PowerShell module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc) devoted to Windows Update.